# Proving the set $\{x ∈ \Bbb Z|x ≥ 3\}$ is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Show that the set $\{x ∈ \Bbb Z|x ≥ 3\}$ is countable.

I'm really stuck on this problem, I have an exam really soon and I'm trying to solve it. So far I know that I have to show that it's onto and one-to-one.

Would I start by saying that $f(n)= 3 + n$ and then showing that it's onto and one-to-one?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you should do.

Comment: It depends a little on your definitions. What is the definition of countable you are using. If it uses a bijection with the natural numbers, then thet is the definition you must adopt. The first natural number is often defined as $1$, in which case you could use $n+2$ rather than $n+3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, precisely!

---

Be sure to be clear about your definition for $f$, of course, in that you're using the definition $$f : \Bbb N \to \{x \in \Bbb Z | x \geq 3\}$$

Seems like a minor detail but it makes your argument clear since, usually, I like focusing these sorts of proofs by looking at the integers. Possibly just a personal quirk, but a lack of ambiguity never hurts.

From there, once you have shown $f$ is a bijection - that is, it is both onto (surjective) and one-to-one (injective) - then you can conclude its domain and codomain have the same cardinality. And thus,

$$|\Bbb N | = \aleph_0 = | \{x \in \Bbb Z | x \geq 3\} |$$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help and the time you took to edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

You already got the answer. A set is countable if there is a one-to-one and onto function between the set and the set of Integers or Natural numbers.
For the set you provided, we can see that there exits a one-to-one and onto function to the set of integers. which is the function
 $f(n) = n+3$ .
To prove its one-to-one just show that 
for any given $n_1$ and $n_2$ , if $f(n_1) = f(n_2)$
then $n_1$ = $n_2$.

To show its onto just show that
 given any $y$ you can find $x$ such that $y = f(x)$.

Both are not difficult to prove.

Comment: Sometimes the definition is given via an injective function $f:S\to \mathbb N$ (bijection with a subset of $\mathbb N$). This has the advantage that finite sets are defined as countable, and it is easy to prove that a subset of a countable set is countable.

Comment: You are right man. but if we could show that there is a bijective function from our set to any known countable set we don't have to stick to N, the set of natural numbers. also if we have a bijective `f:A→Z` and another bijective `g:Z→N`, then `f.g` is a bijective `f.g:A→N`.

Comment: Use mathjax for math formating please.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks bro, I will edit it right away.